# How to use WFS to update the value of a field to an empty string '', not Null？

Tags: geoserver, fields-attributes, wfs, string

I tried to set a field value of a feature to an empty string '' via WFS, but I didn't find a way to make it happen. I use the WFS protocol to send to Geoserver.
I tried the following three methods:
1.

```
<Property><Name>code</Name><Value></Value></Property>
```

The value of the code field is set to Null.
2.

```
<Property><Name>code</Name></Property>
```

The value of the code field is set to Null.
3.

```
<Property><Name>code</Name><Value>''</Value></Property>
```

The value of the code field is set to "''".(The attribute value contains quotation marks).
None of the above methods can solve my problem, so is there a way to set the field value to an empty string via WFS?